# What is wrong with this question ? http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13970/does-duckworth-lewis-method-consider-free-hit-situations

Tags: discussion

I recently asked this : [Does Duckworth-Lewis Method consider "free-hit" situations?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13970/does-duckworth-lewis-method-consider-free-hit-situations)

I got two upvotes, probably because somebody else thought it was a good question and wanted to know the answer.

I also got a (drive-by?) downvote, with no information on what is wrong and what can be done to improve it.

Hence this meta question :
What is wrong with that question ? What can be done to improve that ?

Comment: Downvotes are at the discretion of the user, and it is ideal to get a comment associated with said downvote, but that is not typical. Knowing little about cricket, I can't comment on the quality of your question, but you haven't been flooded with downvotes or close votes from the community, which is a good sign. The only useful commentary here would have to come from the downvoter. Moreover, if we asked about every downvote, we'd be flooded with meta questions.

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ , thanks for the nice input. I only wanted to know if there was something obviously wrong and hence the downvoter did not even leave comment ; Outside perspectives (like yours) would have resolved any obvious deficiencies. With input from you and Philip Kendall , I think this meta question is answered satisfactorily.

Comment: After the following instances of explaining a downvote, I completely understand why users tend not to explain their downvotes (not that they are obligated to do so in the first place): https://i.imgur.com/lbB78Xk.jpg https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14339/what-does-home-runs-allowed-mean/14360?noredirect=1#comment22620_14356 https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14140/is-this-the-oldest-top-ten-in-history#comment21249_14146

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything particularly wrong with it, but don't stress over occasional down votes. They're not the most important thing in the world.

Comment: +1 for "They're not the most important thing in the world"

Comment: Well, +1 , thanks for the confirmation ("don't see anything particularly wrong") and also the advice ("don't stress over occasional down votes"). I think this meta question is satisfactorily answered.